# nginx reverse proxy, single domain, multiple subdirectories

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Having trouble figuring this out.

I have nginx running on home.domain.com.

Within my home network, I have multiple web services that I'd like to access externally through a reverse proxy. No SSL for now, but I'll add that later. I need to set up a reverse proxy on subdirectories of home.domain.com/app{1-3} as I only have a valid cert for home.domain.com.

My current configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default;
        keepalive_timeout 120;
        server_name home.domain.com;

location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://internalIP1:8081/;
 }
 location /app2/ {
         proxy_pass http://internalIP2:5000/;
}
}
```

When I try to access home.domain.com/app1, it should redirect to home.domain.com/app1/login/?next=%2F, but instead goes to home.domain.com/login/?next=%2F. This obviously throws a 404, as it's not available on the nginx server.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Bad idea. Subdomains are much better. App should be aware, that it's run in subfolder and not all apps allow that easily or allow at all.

Comment: SSL Certs are cheap/free for personal use.

Comment: OK, so bad idea. But is it possible?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll have to find a way around. Thanks.

Comment: it depends on app. As I said before, some apps have simple configuration. Others have harcoded to work on root of domain.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.